# Magento and Paypal issue

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway, magento-1.9

I want to setup PayPal Standard as my payment method and after I complete all fields in the checkout one page and choose PayPal as payment method the store is redirect me back to shopping cart and I have this error:

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. Method Specified is not Supported (#81002: Unspecified Method)**

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits : http://paypal-error-81002.blogspot.in/

If you search for the below code  in your php.ini file

```
arg_separator.output = "&amp;"
```

you can see the PHP building the query parameter while starting with "&" Which PayPal doesn't understand. That's why you are getting the above error.

To resolve this just change above code to

```
arg_separator.output = "&"
```

Restart your Apache server.